# JWKS rotation on K8S cluster

Tags: kubernetes, jwt, openid-connect, jwk

I read in documentation of K8S https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#service-account-issuer-discovery

But i can't find in documentation and online when K8S rotates the key? Each day/week/month/other time? And how to configure it.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The official document assumed you have solid OIDC know-how. Here's a good start with example to follow: https://banzaicloud.com/blog/kubernetes-oidc/

Comment: In short it means that if i don't do nothing on my K8S cluster the result of
/openid/v1/jwks

Will be the same and it won't change the key for the token automatically ?

Comment: That's the default behavior. See other possibilities [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/20165#issuecomment-950939312).